# trigger an action (or slash command) from a link

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm trying to use a link (in a `mrkdwn`) to work similar to a button, for design purposes (can integrate it better with text). So when the user clicks that link, I want it to trigger an action or a slash command (along with auth data), so I can open a dialog that shows more info.

I'm wondering if there's any way to achieve this, or if we can create a link for a slash command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called **interactivity** in Slack.

Following are the interactivity entry points :

1. Shortcuts

2. Slash Commands

3. Interactive Components

 https://api.slack.com/interactivity/entry-points

Unfortunately, Links are not valid interactivity component.

 https://api.slack.com/block-kit/interactivity#components